# Electric field on a small sphere too large

Tags: electrostatics, statistical-mechanics

I used the Fermi energy for a given material to find the number of free electrons found on it's surface:

[image]

Where the Fermi energy E_f was given from another calculation using band theory. The solution to the integral is:

[image]

I then multiply the surface area density by the area of the sphere, which in this case has a 25 micron radius:

[image]

Thus providing the total number of free charges on the sphere. Now, I wish to know the electric field on that surface so I use:

$$ E = \frac{k*N_e}{e*r^2} $$

This gives me then some insane order of magnitude: $10^{11} V/m$

This is clearly incorrect as that is way too large. I am fairly certain my surface charge calculation is correct, so is there some piece of physics not being accounted here between the free charge calculated and the E-field? Like, maybe for every atom on the surface, it takes away a certain percentage of the effective charge the free electrons use to generate the field and so there is some dampening parameter involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An electron might be "free" from the total influence of one particular positive ion but there are lots of other **positive** ions with which a free electron interacts with the result that when considering all the free electrons and positive ions the net charge is zero, or put another way, the positive ions also produce an electric field in opposition to that produced by the free electrons.

Comment: I see, so every atom on the surface should essentially cancel out their fields and so the dampening effect is 100% essentially.